# When I have Drawer, I cannot scroll GoogleMaps horizontally in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I can't control GoogleMaps horizontally since I added the ModalNavigationDrawer to the project. When I swipe left and right, I think it thinks I'm doing it for the drawer and I can't navigate the Map screen. I'll leave the codes. I'd appreciate it if you help me what to do.

*Note: I tried all gesturesEnabled options but I can't fixed*

***HomeActivity***

```
val navController = rememberNavController()

val context = LocalContext.current

val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

ModalNavigationDrawer(
    drawerContent = {
        ModalDrawerSheet(
            content = {
                CustomDrawer(onClickList = listOf())
            }
        )
    },
    drawerState = drawerState,
    gesturesEnabled = false
) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 16.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        scope.launch {
                            if (drawerState.isOpen) {
                                drawerState.close()
                            } else {
                                drawerState.open()
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp)
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.menu_image),
                        contentDescription = null,
                    )
                }
                Row(
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.toplan_icon),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp),
                        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(MainRed)
                    )
                    CustomText(
                        text = stringResource(id = R.string.toplan),
                        fontSize = 32,
                        color = MainRed,
                        fontStyle = TextStyle(
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                            fontFamily = khandFamily
                        )
                    )
                }
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        if (hasPermission) {
                            homeViewModel.onAction(
                                HomeAction.ChangeSosDialogState(
                                    true
                                )
                            )
                        } else {
                            permissionState.launchPermissionRequest()
                        }
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(30.dp, 30.dp)
                        .clip(
                            RoundedCornerShape(0.dp)
                        )
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.sos_image),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        drawerContent = {
            CustomDrawer(onClickList = listOf())
        },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .border(
                        width = 1.dp,
                        color = LightGrey20
                    )
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                cutoutShape = CircleShape,
                backgroundColor = Color.White,
            ) {
                BottomNav(navController = navController)
            }
        },
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,
        isFloatingActionButtonDocked = true,
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                shape = CircleShape,
                onClick = {
                    Screen.Alert.route?.let {
                        navController.navigate(it) {
                            popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                saveState = true
                            }
                            launchSingleTop = true
                            restoreState = true
                        }
                    }
                    Screen.Alert.route?.let { navController.navigate(it) }
                },
                backgroundColor = DarkRed
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = Screen.Alert.icon!!),
                    contentDescription = getString(R.string.alert_icon)
                )
            }
        }
    ) {
        it
        TopLanNavGraph(navController = navController)
    }
}
```

***CustomDrawer***

```
@Composable
fun CustomDrawer(
    onClickList: List<Unit>
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth(),
        color = Color.White
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth()
            ) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 20.dp, top = 56.dp, end = 24.dp),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.toplan_icon),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(MainRed),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(vertical = 16.dp, horizontal = 8.dp)
                            .size(36.dp)
                            .drawWithContent {
                                drawCircle(
                                    color = TransparentRed,
                                    radius = 84f,
                                    center = center
                                )
                                this.drawContent()
                            },
                    )
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp)
                    ) {
                        // TODO : Add user name
                        CustomText("user123", 13, color = Black)
                        // TODO : Add user email
                        CustomText("user@example.com", 13, color = MediumGrey10)
                    }
                }
                Divider(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(1.dp)
                        .padding(top = 16.dp)
                        .background(LightGrey5)
                )
                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp, top = 48.dp),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(36.dp),
                    content = {
                        items(4) {
                            ElevatedButton(
                                onClick = {
                                    onClickList[it]
                                },
                                elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevatedButtonElevation(
                                    defaultElevation = 0.dp
                                ),
                                colors = androidx.compose.material3.ButtonDefaults.elevatedButtonColors(
                                    containerColor = Color.White
                                )
                            ) {
                                Image(
                                    painter = painterResource(id = drawerItems[it].icon),
                                    contentDescription = null,
                                    modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp),
                                    colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(MainRed20)
                                )
                                CustomText(
                                    drawerItems[it].title,
                                    16,
                                    color = Black,
                                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp)
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    })
            }
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Divider(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(1.dp)
                        .background(LightGrey5)
                )
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 8.dp, top = 48.dp),
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.copyright),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp),
                    )
                    CustomText(
                        "2024 - topLAN",
                        14,
                        color = MediumGrey20,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 4.dp)
                    )
                }
                CustomText(
                    text = "All rights reserved.",
                    14,
                    color = MediumGrey20,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 48.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

val drawerItems = listOf(
    ComponentItems(R.drawable.user_square, "Profile"),
    ComponentItems(R.drawable.red_settings, "Settings"),
    ComponentItems(R.drawable.feedback, "Contact Us"),
    ComponentItems(R.drawable.logout, "Logout")
)

data class ComponentItems(
    val icon: Int,
    val title: String
)
```